# How to drag and drop a select list (drop down list) with sortable.js

Tags: javascript, sortablejs

I am using [sortable.js](https://sortablejs.github.io/Sortable/) for dragging and dropping html elements. I cannot drag a full dropdown list as it is (select-> options)

I have this select tag

```
<div class="cust-item-group">
                            <select id="ddl" class="cust-item item-element form-control">
                                <option class="cust-item item-element">option</option>
                                <option class="cust-item item-element">option</option>
                                <option class="cust-item item-element">option</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>


<div class="container-fluid ec-wrapper">
                        <br />
                    </div>
```

I need to drag and drop the whole select with child nodes but iam not able to do that. i cant even drag this tag. But i can drag other elements. I am trying to drag the select from "My from div" to "My To div"

***My from div***

```
var items = $(".cust-item-group");
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            new Sortable(items[i], {
                group: {
                    name: 'shared',
                    pull: 'clone',
                    put: false,
                },
                filter: '.el-title',
                animation: 150,
                sort: false,
            });
        }
```

***My To div***

```
var items2 = $(".ec-wrapper");
        for (var i = 0; i < items2.length; i++) {
            new Sortable(items2[i], {
                group: {
                    name: 'shared',
                },
                animation: 150
            });
        }
```

Comment: share your code, pls

Comment: try to replace the <select> with a load of <div> analogues for it

Comment: hi @SmbatPogosyan I have included my code.. Thanks for the response..